# JMS Message.acknowledge() on Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE

Tags: java, jms, tibco

What happens in TIBCO when Message.acknowledge() is invoked in a session with AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE mode?

I mean is this call ignored on client-side? or server-side? or does server perform any action on this call?

The reason I ask is that there is an application which acks messasges in an auto acknowledge session. And a during highload period the method execution time is increased from 0.5 ms to 30 ms.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Java Message Service, Second Edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596522056)

> The acknowledge() method should only
>   be used with the CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE
>   mode; if used with the AUTO_ACKNOWL
>   EDGE or DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE mode, the
>   call is ignored by the JMS provider.

Comment: is this call ignored by client lib or by server?

Comment: @zhilyaev Sorry. I am not sure. Because usually JMS provider means client lib + server.